# Local static initialization without holding a lock avoids a possible deadlock in C++11?

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++11, static-variables

In paper http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2660.htm an algorithm is presented that does not need to hold a lock during the initialization of a local static variable but still causes concurrent flow of control through the variable definition to wait until initialization finished.

The paper says that this has the advantage of avoiding a possible deadlock

> The core problem with function-local static-duration object initialization is that the containing function may be invoked concurrently, and thus the definition may execute concurrently. Failing to synchronize may introduce a race condition. The obvious solution is to synchronize. The problem is that such synchronization may introduce deadlock if the synchronization involves holding a lock while the initializer executes.

Can someone please give an example which demonstrates where the deadlock described above occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to hold a lock during a local static initialization there are two possible designs:

1. Allocate a mutex per static.
2. Allocate just one mutex for all statics.

I'm not 100% positive, but I believe the quote to which you refer implicitly assumes design 2.  And indeed the algorithm introduced in the paper uses just one mutex for all statics (called `mu` in the code).

Under design 2, you get deadlock as described by [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270927/are-function-static-variables-thread-safe-in-gcc/1514444#1514444).  That is, unless you don't actually hold the mutex while doing the initialization.  This is accomplished by having a tri-state flag per static that indicates one of:  not initialized, being initialized, already initialized.  And use the global mutex to set the flag, but unlock it during the initializer.

Comment: ah that makes sense. The paper also says that GCC uses that deadlock-prone algorithm. The linked answer certifies it. thanks.

Comment: This answer has just been down-voted twice.  Anyone care to elaborate?  Or is it just a random, senseless drive by?  I'm into providing accurate information.  I believe this answer to be accurate.  If an elaboration is needed, just ask.  Or at least leave a comment here with a rationale for the down-vote.

Comment: someone had some downvote fun a few hours ago on some of my answers/questions: http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/5457/snapshot96.png . Perhaps it was the same user? If the system thinks it was abusive downvoting it will not count those downvotes though.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple extension of the classic deadlock to the case where one of the locks is compiler-provided.

```
void A2B() { a.Lock(); B(); a.Unlock(); }
void B() { b.Lock(); ...; b.Unlock(); }
void B2A() { b.Lock(); A();  b.Unlock(); }
void A() { a.Lock(); ...; a.Unlock(); }
```

The classic deadlock occurs if one thread calls `A2B()` and another thread calls `B2A()`.

In the static initialization lock, the compiler provides the `b` lock.

```
int A() { a.Lock(); ...; a.Unlock(); return 0; }
void B2A() { static int v = A(); }
void A2B() { a.Lock(); B2A(); a.Unlock(); }
```

If you assume a lock around static initialization, then the code is secretly converted to

```
void B2A() {
    if (!initialized) {
      b.Lock(); // standard double-check-lock
      if (!initialized) v = A();
      initialized=true;
      b.Unlock();
   }
}
```

One thread calls `A2B()` and the other calls `B2A()`.

Comment: This "classic deadlock" is also called lock inversion.

Comment: If we don't hold the lock while initializing `v`, will we not have the same deadlock if others need to wait until `v` has been initialized? One thread calls `B2A` and enters the initialization. The other thread calls `A2B` and locks `a` and calls `B2A` and needs to wait until `v`'s initialization is finished. Now the first thread calls `A` and needs to wait until `a` has been unlocked by `A2B`.

Comment: The original C++ standard avoided this problem by saying "If you call B2A twice, and the first call is still busy trying to initialize `v`, then the second call just continues with an uninitialized `v`".