# GCC's TSAN reports a data race with a thread safe static local

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, gcc, thread-safety

I wrote the following toy example:

```
std::map<char, size_t> getMap(const std::string& s)
{
    std::map<char, size_t> map;
    size_t i = 0;
    for (const char * b = s.data(), *end = b + s.size(); b != end; ++b)
    {
        map[*b] = i++;
    }
    return map;
}

void check(const std::string& s)
{
    //The creation of the map should be thread safe according to the C++11 rules.
    static const auto map = getMap("12abcd12ef");
    //Now we can read the map concurrently.
    size_t n = 0;
    for (const char* b = s.data(), *end = b + s.size(); b != end; ++b)
    {
        auto iter = map.find(*b);
        if (iter != map.end())
        {
            n += iter->second;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "check(" << s << ")=" << n << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(check, "abc");
    std::thread t2(check, "def");
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

According to the C++11 standard, this should not contain any data race (cf. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270927/are-function-static-variables-thread-safe-in-gcc)).

However TSAN with gcc 4.9.2, reports a data race:

```
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=14054)
  Read of size 8 at 0x7f409f5a3690 by thread T2:
    #0 TestServer::check(std::string const&) <null>:0 (TestServer+0x0000000cc30a)
    #1 std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*(char const*))(std::string const&)> >::_M_run() <null>:0 (TestServer+0x0000000cce37)
    #2 execute_native_thread_routine ../../../../../gcc-4.9.2/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:84 (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000b5bdf)

  Previous write of size 8 at 0x7f409f5a3690 by thread T1:
    #0 TestServer::getMap(std::string const&) <null>:0 (TestServer+0x0000000cc032)
    #1 TestServer::check(std::string const&) <null>:0 (TestServer+0x0000000cc5dd)
    #2 std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*(char const*))(std::string const&)> >::_M_run() <null>:0 (TestServer+0x0000000cce37)
    #3 execute_native_thread_routine ../../../../../gcc-4.9.2/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:84 (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000b5bdf)

  Location is global 'TestServer::check(std::string const&)::map' of size 48 at 0x7f409f5a3680 (TestServer+0x00000062b690)

  Thread T2 (tid=14075, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create ../../../../gcc-4.9.2/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors.cc:877 (libtsan.so.0+0x000000047c03)
    #1 __gthread_create /home/Guillaume/Compile/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:662 (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000b5d00)
    #2 std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>) ../../../../../gcc-4.9.2/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:142 (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000b5d00)
    #3 TestServer::main() <null>:0 (TestServer+0x0000000ae914)
    #4 StarQube::runSuite(char const*, void (*)()) <null>:0 (TestServer+0x0000000ce328)
    #5 main <null>:0 (TestServer+0x0000000ae8bd)

  Thread T1 (tid=14074, finished) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create ../../../../gcc-4.9.2/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors.cc:877 (libtsan.so.0+0x000000047c03)
    #1 __gthread_create /home/Guillaume/Compile/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:662 (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000b5d00)
    #2 std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>) ../../../../../gcc-4.9.2/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:142 (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000b5d00)
    #3 TestServer::main() <null>:0 (TestServer+0x0000000ae902)
    #4 StarQube::runSuite(char const*, void (*)()) <null>:0 (TestServer+0x0000000ce328)
    #5 main <null>:0 (TestServer+0x0000000ae8bd)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race ??:0 TestServer::check(std::string const&)
==================
```

**What is wrong here ?**

- is TSan buggy ? (When I am using Clang's toolchain, I get no data race report)
- does GCC emit code which is not thread safe? (I am not using -fno-threadsafe-statics though)
- is my understanding of static locals incorrect?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug.html you may need to rebuild the standard library. (I didn't look at your code so it could be unrelated)

Comment: According to the duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062557/c-multithreading-is-initialization-of-a-local-static-lambda-thread-safe?noredirect=1), this issue was fixed sometimes between gcc 5.4 and gcc 6.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is TSan buggy ? (When I am using Clang's toolchain, I get no data race report)
>   does GCC emit code which is not thread safe? (I am not using -fno-threadsafe->statics though)
>   is my understanding of static locals incorrect?

I believe this is bug in `gcc` part that generate code for `tsan` purposes.

I try this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string message()
{
    static std::string msg("hi");
    return msg;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1([]() { std::cout << message() << "\n"; });
    std::thread t2([]() { std::cout << message() << "\n"; });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

If look at code generate by `clang` and `gcc`, all good,
`__cxa_guard_acquire` is called in both cases for path that init static local variable. But in case of check that we need init `msg` or not we have problem.

The code looks like this

```
if (atomic_flag/*uint8_t*/) {
  lock();
  call_constructor_of_msg();
  unlock();
}
```

in case of `clang` `callq __tsan_atomic8_load` was generated,
but in the case of `gcc` it generate `callq __tsan_read1`.
**Note** that this calls annotate real memory operations,
not do operations by itself.

so it at runtime `tsan` runtime library thinks that all bad,
and we have data race, I report problem here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68338

and looks like it fixed in trunk, but not in current stable release of gcc - 5.2