Is a static variable definition inside a function thread safe
In C++, static variables defined inside a function are thread safe by default. So, are static variables in Rust have the same thread safety property or I need to use some sync primitive?

the variable initialization is thread safe, not the variable usage itself. C++ doesn't have a thread safe runtime, you have to implement mechanisms yourself (check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270927/are-function-static-variables-thread-safe-in-gcc)

If the value is not const constructible, you'll need to use a sync primitive like std::sync::LazyLock. If you try to initialize a static without an appropriate primitive, the compiler will complain.

@user4815162342 using sync primitive will incur overhead. Would like to know how C++ is achieving this without any sync primitive.

"In C++, static variables defined inside a function are thread safe by default" – [citation needed].

@Harry In C++ the compiler inserts the synchronization code for you automatically. For example, note the calls to guard acquire/release in this code.

@cafce25 Citations seem to be provided in this answer, as well as this one. (I haven't verified them or studied them in detail, but they seem convincing enough.)

@user4815162342 neither of these state anything about thread safety beyond initialization. OP claims the variable itself is thread safe, which is a stronger requirement and not supported by either quote.

@cafce25 Ok, I see what you mean. I'm pretty sure they were referring to initialization, but I can't speak for the OP, so I'll leave it at that.


In C++, static variables defined inside a function are thread safe by default.

No, they are not. Only their initialization is thread safe.
The thread safety guarantee is very similar (functionally) to Rust's LazyLock. Except C++ does this under the hood. It will insert synchronization primitives for you, behind the scenes.

So, are static variables in Rust have the same thread safety property or I need to use some sync primitive?

Rust statics can only be initialized through const expressions. And such expressions are always evaluated at compile time. Meaning the variable will be initialized before runtime even starts (it will be baked into the assembly). This is quite limiting compared to what you can do with C++. But on the other hand, that way there are no hidden costs and thread safety (of initialization) is not even a topic.
If you want to freely initialize a static, you need wrap your value with LazyLock (or similar), which ultimately leads to the same thing that C++ does, except explicitly.
Usage is of course a different story. And neither C++ nor Rust guarantees thread safety of the underlying object once initialized.

Here is a proof that mutable static variables inside function are not thread-safe by default. It is possible to make these static variables unsafe, but the programming language makes the programmer to use thread-safe static variables.
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn increment_counter() -> (i32, i32) {
    static SAFE_COUNTER: Mutex<i32> = Mutex::new(0);

    // mutable statics can be mutated by multiple threads: aliasing violations or data races will cause undefined behavior
    static mut UNSAFE_COUNTER: i32 = 0;
    unsafe {
        UNSAFE_COUNTER += 1;
    }

    let mut safe_counter = SAFE_COUNTER.lock().unwrap();
    *safe_counter += 1;

    (*safe_counter, unsafe { UNSAFE_COUNTER })
}

fn main() {
    let n: i32 = 1000000;
    (0..n - 1).into_par_iter().for_each(|_| {
        increment_counter();
    });
    let res = increment_counter();
    println!("thread-safe: {}, not-thread-safe: {}", res.0, res.1);
}

This output shows that the static variables inside functions are not thread-safe by default, but the programmer has a protection by having to mark unsafe static variables into unsafe clause.
thread-safe: 1000000, not-thread-safe: 953687

